# Iterate rows in df and insert new row with result of column operations of the matching rows

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to create a new row with difference in values of a particular column of two other rows with matching columns and another variable column

```
Project    Cost element  Version  Value  Cur
A            A1              000  -10000  USD
A            A1              ASO   -8000   USD
A            A1              CHO     -2000   USD  
A            A1              CHr      -2000   USD   create third & fourth rows
```

Similarly for costements starting with 5 say B1.  the delta row should have version ADJ.

After browsing through old posts got some looping logic.. but feel it is too cumbersome.  Any smart ideas welcome.

```
for i in range(0,len(Project_Forecast_Source)):
    if Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i] =='4020101000' :     
        if (Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i] == Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i+1] and 
            Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i] == Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i+1] and 
            Project_Forecast_Source['Version'].loc[i] == "000")   :                                                                                   
            Val = float(Project_Forecast_Source['Amount'].loc[i] - Project_Forecast_Source['Amount'].loc[i+1])
            row_number = Project_Forecast_Source.index.max()+1
            row_Value = [Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i], Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i+1],"CHO", Project_Forecast_Source['ObCur'].loc[i], Val] 
            Project_Forecast_Source.loc[row_number] = row_Value  
            row_number1 = Project_Forecast_Source.index.max()+1
            row_Value1 = [Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i], Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i+1],"CHR", Project_Forecast_Source['ObCur'].loc[i], Val] 
            Project_Forecast_Source.loc[row_number1] = row_Value1  
    else :
            if (Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i] == Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i+1] and 
                Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i] == Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i+1] and  
                Project_Forecast_Source['Version'].loc[i] == "000")  :
                Val = float(Project_Forecast_Source['Amount'].loc[i] - Project_Forecast_Source['Amount'].loc[i+1])
                row_number = Project_Forecast_Source.index.max()+1
                row_Value = [Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i], Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i],"ADJ", Project_Forecast_Source['ObCur'].loc[i], Val] 
                Project_Forecast_Source.loc[row_number] = row_Value  

            elif ((Project_Forecast_Source['Version'].loc[i] == "ASO") and  
#                 (Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i] != Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i+1]) and   
#                 (Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i] != Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i-1]) and
                 (Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i] != Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i+1]) and
                 (Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i] != Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i-1]))  :
                  Val = 0.0 - float(Project_Forecast_Source['Amount'].loc[i])
                  row_number = Project_Forecast_Source.index.max()+1
                  row_Value = [Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i], Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i],"ADJ", Project_Forecast_Source['ObCur'].loc[i], Val] 
                  Project_Forecast_Source.loc[row_number] = row_Value
            elif Project_Forecast_Source['Version'].loc[i] == "000" :
                Val = float(Project_Forecast_Source['Amount'].loc[i])
                row_number = Project_Forecast_Source.index.max()+1
                row_Value = [Project_Forecast_Source['ProjDef'].loc[i], Project_Forecast_Source['CostElem'].loc[i],"ADJ", Project_Forecast_Source['ObCur'].loc[i], Val] 
                Project_Forecast_Source.loc[row_number] = row_Value
```

Comment: try rephrasing your question... it's blurry

Comment: I gave an example..That will be clear .  I would like create a new row with diff value for the first two rows